# Can we give multiple URL's to one web app in Microsoft azure cloud

Tags: azure

I have one sample MVC application and hosted on azure cloud. On the azure cloud I have created one web app. 
Now, I want to create a multi tenant environment in which I want to create different URL's for multiple customer of same application. Is this possible?

Comment: So you don't want multiple instance of the _application_, you only want to point to the _same_ application from _multiple URLs_, right? And will you be doing so on your own custom domain? Because if so, DNS records would be your answer: have multiple subdomains (one.example.com and two.example.com) point to the same Azure Web App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to purchase a domain name for example "**sudhanshupal.com**"

You can then add sub-domains (A/CNAME) for every customer and point it to the corresponding resource.

- customer1.sudhanshupal.com
- customer2.sudhanshupal.com
- customer3.sudhanshupal.com

**. . .**

HTH.

Comment: I need to create multi tenancy environment. Each tenant will connect to different database but access the same web application.

Comment: Your multi-tenancy is for DB only, which is not a good design. It would be better if you create separate web apps for separate tenants. You can have them as part of the same app service plan. You are anyways charged for the app service plan and not web apps. Also this will keep it isolated.

If you still insist on single web app - multiple database, then you will have to handle the routing of the request for corresponding clients in your web application which will be based on the incoming host header for the request. There are lot of caveats to this from what I see.